# Testing on multiple OSs simultaneously

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, operating-system

I test my application on different OS like Home, Ultimate, Business, etc. which is repetitive and tiring. I want to get rid of this so that I test it once and the work gets done for all the OS.
For some reason, all my tests are manual and can't be automated.
So, my idea was that I can have multiple OSs installed on different CPUs, each having its own dedicated monitor. But I shall use a single mouse and keyboard. And when I click on one button in a specific OS, the same button gets clicked for on other monitors as well parallely. 
Is there any software available in market that could help me achieve this? 
I understand that this would require me to have extra hardwares as well and I am okay with procuring new hardwares.
Please suggest if anyone is aware of this kind of software and hardware.

Thanks,
Saswat

Comment: Not a genius. But to me, looks like it is not going to be easy and I have not heard anything similar till date actually.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as running different OSs on different CPUs simultaneously. You can have different OSs installed on the same machine but you need to reboot to switch between them. Alternatively, you can install virtual machines with different OSs and use them. If you're testing application without HW interaction, that should fit you just fine.

If you want several OSs running on real machines, you'll need a controller machine for managing it over network. In any case, either with a remote controller or VMs you'll need to create custom scripts (I guess a commercial software should be available as well).

Comment: I am not the Downvoter for sure. But it looks like OP is asking something else and well, very creative approach for his solution and I feel is not that easy. Your suggested solution is a normal approach and thats what OP is trying to skip. OP states...`Repetitive and Tiring`...so all he wants is a single click for all his tests on any platform.